# Export a parameterized SSRS report from C# code

Tags: c#, reporting-services, export, parameterized

Currently I have SQL Reporting Services 2005 set up, with the report manager at a URL on which users can access reports. The reports are working great there.

My issue is trying to generate these reports in C# .net 4.0 code **without any user interaction** (such as using the report viewer on screen). I would like to generate and export a report to a PDF file in a C# .net application. The reports have required parameters so I would need to pass the parameters to the report. How can I do this?

I have been searching around online, and either I'm using the wrong keywords or there isn't much information on this. I am quite amazed at how difficult it has been to find information on this, as I would expect it to be a fairly common question. Any and all advice / help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string outputPath = "C:\Temp\PdfReport.pdf";

ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ServerReport serverReport = new ServerReport();
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"path/to/report";
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://...");
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new 
    System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)

List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("parameterName", "value"));

string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;
string[] streams;
Warning[] warnings;
byte[] pdfBytes= serverReport.Render("PDF", string.Empty, out mimeType, 
    out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);

// save the file
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this answer in asp.net core but not working! can you guide me?

Answer (score 2):

I've not used the 2005 version of the ReportViewer much. But you should be able to do something like this:

```
ServerReport serverReport = new ServerReport();
serverReport.ReportPath = "path/to/report";
serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = ...;
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = "http://....";
serverReport.SetParameters(...);
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;
string[] streams;
Warning[] warnings;
byte[] asPdf = serverReport.Render("PDF", string.Empty, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);
```

The general takeaway being that `ServerReport` and `LocalReport` were both designed to be usable outside of a ReportViewer.

Comment: Actually I appear to be wrong in that `ServerReport` lacks a public constructor whereas `LocalReport` does (I've used LocalReport a lot more). You should still be able to instantiate a ReportViewer and then just use its ServerReport object from there.

Comment: What you submitted was close and a nice start, but it was missing how to write the credentials and how to actually write the file to PDF. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattGreer I have copied this code in VS 2017 not working, can you please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to open the report as a PDF. If you just need to open a pdf with parameters in a browser window then you can use the report server itself and specify *Format=PDF* as a querystring option.

Example:

> http://myServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyApplicationReports%2fAcutalReportFileName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&ParamOneId=31943&ParamTwoDate=17072015

I hope this saves someone else out there some time!